# Add a loading overlay onto google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay, loading

Hi guys we have a google map v3 which loads in markers when dragged via ajax - I'm all ok with that - I'm just wondering how to add a loading bar on my map - I'm already using

```
container.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=60);";
                container.style.opacity = 0.6;
```

and something else to stop dragging.

What's the best way to do that - if poss I would like to use some html and not an image.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you just want something that will place a rectangle containing text on the map, essentially a label, you may want to consider an: [InfoBox](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox)
2. If you want something that dynamically displays progress, you may want to use the: [ProgressBarControl](http://www.basicslabs.com/Projects/progressBar/)

Comment: Thanks went for InfoxBox - just to fill a few people in - you can attach the Infobox to the map without a marker - but you need to include the libs.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/src/infobox.js"></script>
To use it.
Hope that helps somone - ta to Sean for the answer.

Comment: The link to "ProgressBarControl" doesn't work - fails to load or redirects to some other page. Really strange ...

Comment: Looks like the basiclabs.com site has been hijacked.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and solved it by adding a layer over the map (In my case, I just need the loading, and I don't have any other reason to add another plugin):

HTML:

```
<div id="holder" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="overlay standard hidden">&nbsp</div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#holder {
    position: relative;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

div.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.overlay.standard { background: #fff url(/image/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%; }
```